# jQuery Loaded in noConflict Mode, Can't Access $ Even if Passed as Function Parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

I have jQuery loaded with `jQuery.noConflict()` at the top (in WordPress).

Then I have the following custom function:

```
var equalizeHeights = function(){
  $('.header').height(500);
}
```

Which I call on `.ready()` this way:

```
jQuery(function($){
  equalizeHeights();
});
```

The `$` in the function parameter is supposed to make the shorthand version of the jQuery variable available throughout that block, but the line where I actually try to set the height in the `equalizeHeights()` function returns an error in the console.

`Uncaugth TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function`

I am sure that I have the library loaded, and this is not the issue, since if I `console.log` the `$` variable immediately before calling `equalizeHeights()` it returns a valid jQuery object. The issue is that `$` is not inherited by the child function for some reason.

Making `$` global and assigning `$ = jQuery` is not an option.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your scope block look like? You can always pass the specific  jQuery object into equalizeHeights. e.g. `equalizeHeights($)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `equalizeHeights` in the scope of the ready callback function

```
jQuery(function($){
    equalizeHeights($);
    var equalizeHeights = function($){
        $('.header').height(500);
    }
});
```

if you need it to be global,

```
var equalizeHeights;
jQuery(function($){
    equalizeHeights = function($){
        $('.header').height(500);
    }
    equalizeHeights($);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try:

```
    jQuery(function($){
        equalizeHeights($);
    });

    var equalizeHeights = function($){
        $('.header').height(500);
    }
```

and passing the $ through the function call. Otherwise, the reference to jQuery being '$' is being lost.

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but it's not a very maintainable option since I might call dozens of functions on `.ready()` and providing a parameter for each doesn't seem like good practice to me. Aren't parent variable values supposed to be inherited on child function calls?

Comment: `Aren't parent variable values supposed to be inherited on child function calls?` Depends on where the variable was declared. In this case, not in scope of the function, unless you place `equalizeHeights` within the `function($){}`.